# onStateChange replace class element with new element youtube chromeless

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

**Question in reference to** : http://jsfiddle.net/yusaf/VVEY9/55/

When the video player state has changed so that `onStateChange(0)` ie the video has ended, how would I hide the `.pause` element and add a replay button to start the video over and once restarted show the `.pause` element

```
<object width="640" height="385"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/2Qj8PhxSnhg&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/2Qj8PhxSnhg&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="640" height="385"></embed></object>

<a class="play" href="#">play</a>
<a class="pause" href="#">pause</a>
<a class="replay" href="#">replay</a>



$(document).ready(function(){
 var obj = $('object')
     .wrap('<div id="test"></div>')
     .find('embed').attr('src', function(i,s){return s+'&enablejsapi=1&version=3'}).end()
     .find('param[name=movie]').attr('value', function(i,v){return v+'&enablejsapi=1&version=3'}).end()
     .detach()
     .appendTo($('#test'));
    $('.pause').hide();

 $('.play').click(function(){
  obj.find('embed')[0].playVideo();
  $(".pause").show();
  $(".play").hide();   
 });
 $('.pause').click(function(){
  obj.find('embed')[0].pauseVideo();
    $(".pause").hide();
  $(".play").show();
 })
});
$('.replay').click(function(){
  obj.find('embed')[0].playVideo();  
 });
```

Comment: +1 for putting a fiddle and being really descriptive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you will need to use Youtube API either [iframe](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) or [flash](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference). Why? simply because your current code is not crossbrowser compliant. And also there are plenty of methods and helpers to use there.

Secondly, you can assign a `onPlayerStateChange` function using one of the mentioned APIs, which will be called when video ends (on iframe api you can use some predefined constants such as `YT.PlayerState.ENDED`

Check a demo out at http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#polling_the_player

The code should look similar to:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(evt) {
    if (evt.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
          // do your jQuery login to hide and blah blah here.
    }
}
```